# WordPress homepage too slow, posts work fine? Framework issue?

Tags: wordpress

I have been searching solution for the issue of slow server response for my wordpress website https://www.pointmovies.com/ 
Homepage is taking 6 to 7 seconds to load, but the posts do not take that long. There is no late server response for posts.  I have made some tests:

For homepage: https://tools.pingdom.com/#!/cxw0LG/http://www.pointmovies.com/

For Posts: https://tools.pingdom.com/#!/dF8QGr/https://www.pointmovies.com/movie/dangal-2016/

Is this any framework issue, caused by theme? or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You have a LOT of images on the homepage. A quick glance at [gtMetrix](https://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.pointmovies.com/TwQCsLB7) shows that compressing those images could save megabytes on the home page load time.

I'd also recommend a WordPress caching plugin. I prefer [Comet Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/comet-cache/), but try a few and see which one fits your skill level and performs best for you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. Actually this is not the load time. 3 to 4 seconds are being taken by the server to respond only, after that the receiving starts.